# instance variables has more priority than data descriptors?

Tags: python

From doc [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/descriptor.html), there's a  priority conclusion

```
   The implementation works through a precedence chain that gives data descriptors priority over 
   instance variables, instance variables priority over non-data descriptors, and assigns lowest 
   priority to __getattr__() if provided.
```

But when i tried with my trial as below:

```
class RevealAccess(object):
    """A data descriptor that sets and returns values
       normally and prints a message logging their access.
    """

    def __init__(self, initval=None, name='var'):
        self.val = initval
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        print('Retrieving', self.name)
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print('Updating' , self.name)
        self.val = val


class MyClass(object):
    x = RevealAccess(10, 'x')


m = MyClass()
m.x = 1
print(m.__dict__)       # {}
print(MyClass.__dict__) # {'__module__': '__main__', 'x': <__main__.RevealAccess object at 0x0000018EB4C6D908>, 'y': 5, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'MyClass' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'MyClass' objects>, '__doc__': None}

print(m.x)    #   1 why this value is not 10 here          
print(m.__dict__)
```

Why the value is still 1 after I set it 10 in data descriptor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is 1 because you set it to 1. 10 was only the initial value.

Your descriptor's `__init__` sets `self.val` to `10` (where `self` is the descriptor), but then your `__set__` is triggered on `m.x = 1` and sets `self.val` to `1`. Your `__get__` then returns `self.val`, which is `1` now.

Nothing is receiving priority over the data descriptor. The data descriptor handles the attribute the whole time.